# ROC curves using pROC on R: Calculating lab value a threshold equates to

Tags: r, statistics, roc, proc-r-package

I am using pROC to provide the ROC analysis of blood tests. I have calculated the ROC curve, AUC and am using the ci.coords function to provide the spec, sens, PPV and NPV at a provided specificity (with 95% CI).

I would like to be able to say at what value of blod test this is, for instance at 1.2 the sens is x, spec is y, NPV is c, PPV is d. Ideally I ould have the data for a table like:

```
Lab value | Sens | Spec | NPV | PPV
```

I don't seem to be able to get this from the methodology I am currently using?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks

Currently

````
spred1 = predict(smodel1)

sroc1 = roc(EditedDF1$any_abnormality, spred1)

ci.coords(sroc1, x=0.95,  input="sensitivity", transpose = FALSE, ret=c("sensitivity","specificity","ppv","npv"))```
````

Comment: What's `smodel1`? It's impossible to answer if you don't show that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you gave no reproducible example let's use the one that comes with the package

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
roc1 <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
```

The package comes with the function `coords` which lists specificity and sensititivity at different thresholds:

```
> coords(roc1)
   threshold specificity sensitivity
1       -Inf  0.00000000  1.00000000
2      0.035  0.00000000  0.97560976
3      0.045  0.06944444  0.97560976
4      0.055  0.11111111  0.97560976
5      0.065  0.13888889  0.97560976
6      0.075  0.22222222  0.90243902
7      0.085  0.30555556  0.87804878
8      0.095  0.38888889  0.82926829
9      0.105  0.48611111  0.78048780
10     0.115  0.54166667  0.75609756
...
```

From there you can use the function `ci.coords` that you already have used to complete the table by whatever data you desire.

Comment: is the threshold given here the value of S100B of which a value of which the spec and the sens is given? As in the threshold of 0.035=S100B level of 0.035 pg/ml?

Comment: Yes, those are thresholds to compare to `aSAH$s100b`. If you look at the values as in `table(aSAH$s100b)` and compare that to `roc1$thresholds` you will find that the thresholds lie between the `s100b` values so every value is unambiguously below or above each threshold.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(pROC)
#> Type 'citation("pROC")' for a citation.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pROC'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     cov, smooth, var
data(aSAH)

roc <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b,
  levels = c("Good", "Poor")
)
#> Setting direction: controls < cases

tibble(threshold = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) %>%
  mutate(
    data = threshold %>% map(~ {
      res <- roc %>% ci.coords(x = .x, ret = c("sensitivity", "specificity", "ppv", "npv"))
      
      # 97.5%
      list(
        sens = res$sensitivity[[3]],
        spec = res$specificity[[3]],
        ppv = res$ppv[[3]],
        npv = res$npv[[3]]
      )
    })
  ) %>%
  unnest_wider(data)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#>    threshold   sens  spec   ppv    npv
#>        <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1       0   1      0     0.363 NA    
#>  2       0.1 0.927  0.5   0.5    0.917
#>  3       0.2 0.780  0.903 0.784  0.867
#>  4       0.3 0.634  0.917 0.769  0.8  
#>  5       0.4 0.561  0.958 0.85   0.782
#>  6       0.5 0.439  1     1      0.755
#>  7       0.6 0.366  1     1      0.735
#>  8       0.7 0.317  1     1      0.72 
#>  9       0.8 0.195  1     1      0.686
#> 10       0.9 0.122  1     1      0.667
#> 11       1   0.0732 1     1      0.655
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>